# How to customize DataTable icon of react-native-paper . library

Tags: react-native

When I execute the code, the icons appear as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZnDP.png)

I desire to customize these icons or resolve the issue according to the instructions provided in the documentation. Thank you for your assistance.

Upon running the code, the icons within my application or webpage are displayed as depicted in the image description. Nevertheless, I wish to make modifications to these icons to better suit my preferences or follow the guidelines specified in the documentation to rectify the current presentation